# parse only first level of json

Tags: php, arrays, json, string

I have this kind of json file:

```
{
"params": {
    "apiKey": "key",
    "sessionId": "123433890",
    "lang": "en",
    "timezone": "America/New_York",
    "query": "hi all",
    "latitude": "37.459157",
    "longitude": "-122.17926",
    "context": "[{"
     name ": "
     weather ","
     lifespan ": 4}]"
}
```

}

It is not valid json because of

```
"context": "[{"
     name ": "
     weather ","
     lifespan ": 4}]"
```

and I can not decode it with json_decode.

So I wonder if it possible to decode only first keys. So the result would possibly look like

```
    array(1) {
  'parameters' =>
  array(8) {
    'apiKey' =>
    string(32) "key"
    'sessionId' =>
    string(10) "123433890"
    'lang' =>
    string(2) "en"
    'timezone' =>
    string(16) "America/New_York"
    'query' =>
    string(16) "hi all"
    'latitude' =>
    string(9) "37.459157"
    'longitude' =>
    string(10) "-122.17926"
    'context' =>
    string(16) "[{"name ": "weather ","lifespan ": 4}]"
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Also this is valid json, but it can not be decoded with json_decode.

```
    {
    "query": [
        "and for tomorrow"
    ],
    "contexts": "[{'name':'weather', 'lifespan' : 4}]",
    "location": {
        "latitude": 37.459157,
        "longitude": -122.17926
    },
    "timezone": "America/New_York",
    "lang": "en",
    "sessionId": "1234567890"
}
```

Comment: Are you making the json yourself?

Comment: @KinshukLahiri see update

Comment: @Saba The above json is not valid. Its missing `{` as suggested by @Paul

Comment: @PaulCrovella sorry, see again please.

Comment: I think single quotes should be escaping somehow.

Comment: @Saba Checkout the answer. And try it.

Comment: @PaulCrovella no, without escaping single quote it show error to me like
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'name' (T_STRING)

Comment: @PaulCrovella okay can you show working code how to decode it?

Comment: @PaulCrovella thank you!! I did not know about this "<<<'JSON'", where to read more detailes??

Comment: @PaulCrovella thank you. But if this json pass to me in request body and I obtained it like
$this->body = json_decode($this->request->getContent(), true);
so how to make it work like in your answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124530/discussion-between-saba-and-paul-crovella).

Comment: It would be better to interpret `context` as an array than a string. I have posted an answer that does that and provides code to "fix" your malformed JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is indeed not valid. It should look like this:

```
{
  "params": {
    "apiKey": "key",
    "sessionId": "123433890",
    "lang": "en",
    "timezone": "America/New_York",
    "query": "hi all",
    "latitude": "37.459157",
    "longitude": "-122.17926",
    "context": [{"name":"weather","lifespan": 4}]
  }
}
```

The error is that the `context` key value was put in quotes, while it should not have been, since it is not a string, but a nested object.

If you have no control over the file, and cannot fix it, then you could use this code, which will try to fix it for you after you have read it:

```
// Invalid JSON as read from your file:
$json = '{
  "params": {
    "apiKey": "key",
    "sessionId": "123433890",
    "lang": "en",
    "timezone": "America/New_York",
    "query": "hi all",
    "latitude": "37.459157",
    "longitude": "-122.17926",
    "context": "[{"
     name ": "
     weather ","
     lifespan ": 4}]"
  }
}';
// Fix malformed JSON
$json = preg_replace_callback('~"([\[{].*?[}\]])"~s', function ($match) {
    return preg_replace('~\s*"\s*~', "\"", $match[1]);
}, $json);
// Now you can do:
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
```

The result of the above code is that `$arr` will contain this:

```
array (
  'params' => array (
    'apiKey' => 'key',
    'sessionId' => '123433890',
    'lang' => 'en',
    'timezone' => 'America/New_York',
    'query' => 'hi all',
    'latitude' => '37.459157',
    'longitude' => '-122.17926',
    'context' => array (
      array (
        'name' => 'weather',
        'lifespan' => 4,
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/652483).

Note how also the `context` property has structured information (an array).

#### Explanation of the code

First the following pattern is searched for:

```
~"([\[{].*?[}\]])"~s
```

The `~` are just delimiters for the regular expression. Then:

- `"`: matches a double quote
- `(  ...  )`: defines the part that we want to actually get: we want to remove the outer most double quotes, so they are not within these parentheses.
- `[\[{]`: matches either one of these literal characters: `[{`
- `.*?`: matches any character, but not more than necessary to continue (the `?` makes it non-greedy, i.e. lazy).
- `[}\]]`: matches either one of these literal characters: `}]`
- `s`: this is a modifier that will make the `.` also match with newline characters

For every match, `preg_replace_callback` will call the function we pass as second argument, passing it an array. The first element of the array will be the complete match, while the second will represent the captured part, i.e. the part between parentheses (that one has our interest):

```
$match[1]
```

We apply a new regular expression on that, which removes all white-space around double quotes, including newlines. This way, the key names, like `name` will be tightly wrapped in double quotes, as it should be:

```
~\s*"\s*~s
```

Again, the `~` are just delimiters for the regular expression.

- `\s*`: matches any number of white-space, including newlines

The string that is so modified must be returned to the outer `preg_replace_callback` function, which will use it to insert it in the final result string.

#### Fixing the Real Cause

Of course, if you *do* have control over the file, or how it is generated, then fix the cause of this issue.

Note that valid JSON does *not* use single quotes to delimit strings. They must be double quotes.

Comment: excellent!! that is what I need. If you can explain how this preg works, I would be very thankful to you!

Comment: what preg should look like to fix not only 

"context": "[{"name ": "weather ", "lifespan ": 4}]" 

but  also 

"contexts": "{"name": "Sam"}"

Comment: I added explanations and adapted the regex for dealing with `"{" .... "}"` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The second json you mentioned that can't be decoded.

Here is the solution:

```
$test = '{
"query": [
    "and for tomorrow"
],
"contexts": "[{\'name\':\'weather\', \'lifespan\' : 4}]",
"location": {
    "latitude": 37.459157,
    "longitude": -122.17926
},
"timezone": "America/New_York",
"lang": "en",
"sessionId": "1234567890"
}';

$j = json_decode($test);

print_r($j);
```

Answer (score -2):

How you are generating this json

Probably there is some error in you json generation

**The correct json should be generated as below**

```
{
    "params": {
        "apiKey": "key",
        "sessionId": "123433890",
        "lang": "en",
        "timezone": "America/New_York",
        "query": "hi all",
        "latitude": "37.459157",
        "longitude": "-122.17926",
        "context": [{
         "name ":" ",
         "weather" :"a",
         "lifespan ": 4}]
    }

}
```

You can check the same [Here](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=f17ff153b19dee1b4cdea05d856a1ce9)

**I think the values that you are passing to the context should be an array which you are missing.**

Comment: Thanks but if it will be valid json then no questing appears :)) Think like it is not a json object but string.